# How do I isolate unwanted PHP error messages?

Tags: php, apache

I am using wamp and need to know why I am getting server error messages appear in all browsers. (see grab). I have turned error display off in php.ini and cannot see anywhere in the httpd.conf file that would be displaying these. I would appreciate some help as to how I can troubleshoot this problem. If anyone requires further code or information, I would be happy to supply at fiddle.

I am using php5.3.5 and apache 2.0.53.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Do you have an error message / screen grab we can see? Whilst suppressing the messages works, it's usually best to fix the root cause of the error

Comment: do you have a .htaccess file? check that. try loading a php file with just <?php echo phpinfo(); ?> and check the config entries for logging, and config sources. ps there's no [screen] grab listed here, as implied by your question

Comment: Excuse my pontification but turning off errors won't fix them. Your best bet might be to go for the fuzzy feeling you get when your app is running error free because you fixed all the errors.

Comment: sorry. Here is the error grab. I have now added to original question. thanks

Comment: @johnp I take your point and totally agree. I have recently changed to php5 and need to know what is producing the errors that i posted.

Comment: @smcphill thanks. will try that and report back. thanks

Comment: @bollo cool, your problem seems to be that you might be including a file using http : http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

Comment: @johnp there are no include files that use http. for example <?php include('header.php'); ?> loads the header from main.php and it is saying in the error that header.php is the culprit and there are no includes in there. thanks

Comment: @smcphill there is nothing in the .htaccess file that would produce this. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`display_errors` is changeable `PHP_INI_ALL` ([documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php)).

This means it can be enabled in `.htaccess`, or in a running script using `ini_set()`. Check your .htaccess files; note that the server (in default config) checks .htaccess files in parent directories as well - so if your site is in `/var/www/example.com/htdocs`, check for `.htaccess` in each of the directories in this path.

Comment: I only have 1 .htaccess file. Also, I cannot see ini_set() in any of my code. thanks

Comment: @bollo: OK, so that can be ruled out (I remember being bitten by `.htaccess` located in `/var` - it took me a long time to even look for it *there*. :D).

Comment: I am using wamp so there is no var directory as far as I can see? thanks

Comment: In php info file, display_errors is shown as on. In the php.ini file it is disabled: ;display_errors = On. why is this happening. I have checked for multiple ini files, but can only see the 1.

Comment: @bollo: That was an example - in my post, `/var` is in the directory path of the website (which has DocumentRoot in `/var/www/example.com/htdocs`). Also, try setting it to `Off` in php.ini; if it's commented out, the default is used - and that default might be `On`.

Comment: @bollo: You're welcome :D You may want to accept [my *other* answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6546690/how-do-i-isolate-unwanted-php-error-messages/6548514#6548514) instead of this one, if that describes the root of the problem better - I made an answer from that comment.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure `display_errors` isn't being set at runtime by some function in your code?  [`ini_set`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php) can be used to set that value at runtime, as shown in this PHP doc example:

```
<?php
echo ini_get('display_errors');

if (!ini_get('display_errors')) {
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
}

echo ini_get('display_errors');
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

> i have turned error display off in php.ini

Did you check that the php.ini file you changed/checked was the one PHP is using? (shown by phpinfo())

Did you restart the webserver after changing the php.ini file?

What grab? If the q's above don't resolve your problem please provide the text of the error message.

Comment: I checked the correct php.ini file and i using the correct one. And yes, I restarted the server. I have now included grabs of errors. thanks

Answer (score 1):

looks like you are using zend framework. if you do not want to show error messages. (anyway turning off errors won't fix them)

option 1.
change application environment.
edit your bootstrap file (in public directory) 
find following lines

```
defined('APPLICATION_ENV')
|| define('APPLICATION_ENV', (getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') ? getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') : 'development'));
```

to following

```
defined('APPLICATION_ENV')
|| define('APPLICATION_ENV', (getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') ? getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') : 'production'));
```

option 2.
edit your application.ini (in application/configs directory) file. change all phpSettings.display_errors=1 to phpSettings.display_errors = 0.

anyway I recommend using option 2.

but remember turning off errors won't fix them. if you post your code may be we can help.

Comment: i do not have a application/configs directory within wamp. Where would I find it? many thanks

Answer (score 1):

From the OP's comment:

> In php info file, display_errors is shown as on. In the php.ini file it is disabled: ;display_errors = On. why is this happening. I have checked for multiple ini files, but can only see the 1.

If the option is *commented out* in `php.ini`, it's not disabled: it means "use default". IIRC, the default here is `On`. Add the line `display_errors = Off` to php.ini.