# Codeigniter shows blank page with no error

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have one codeigniter app which was working fine on localhost. When I uploaded the same on server, it shows blank page & returning no error. I have also used approx. all method mentioned on Stackoverflow or other sites. Kindly guide me.

**UPDATES**

I found that there is

```
$this->load->database();
```

When i remove this, it works, but when I add again, it doesn't work. My site is on shared hosting server

Comment: check the is your `error_reporting` not to be off

Comment: Please check this link first http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6587515/how-to-display-php-errors-in-code-output

Comment: @LalitSharma, I have already enable error_reporting by using ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE); & my environment set to production

Comment: Then you have to put echo and exit flag in default controller and so on. Hope you will find the problem.

Comment: check ur error log @CoolPerfectionist

Comment: @LalitSharma can you explain how it can be used. My default controller is welcome

Comment: put echo 'here'; exit; in yout index method of the welcome controller, if method is not created then create it

Comment: I tried nothing works. No error is showing in error log

Comment: I have checked that there is problem with  $this->load->database(); when i remove this from my controller, it works

Comment: it seems CI cannot connect your database and may be your error reporting is off that's why you cannot see any error message.

Comment: @ShaifulIslam, I have enabled error reporting. But i can;t understand why my db is not getting connected to CI while my credentials are correct

Comment: Just autoload database make sure you have but your details in you can not load the database library like that has to be done by autoload.

Comment: where are you trying this code? web server/localhost

Comment: @guys solved this issue, there is issue with Server PHP version. Now My website is running successfully. Thanks to all participants

Answer (score 4):

in index.php file located in your base check

```
define('ENVIRONMENT', 'development');
```

if it's not then define it same.

Or you can write

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

At end of this file, definitely it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue 
Apparently firefox doesn't show any errors (blank page) but chrome shows error 500.

To fix it you need to install php's fileinto extention (extension=php_fileinfo.dll)

Search based on your OS to see how to do it.

I am using XAMPP in windows 7 - I did it as follows :

```
1-go to xampp/php/php.ini

2-change  
     ;php_fileinfo.dll
to 
      php_fileinfo.dll

3-save the file
4-restart apache from xampp control
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to go on root directrory of ci and open index.php file where you get enviornment which by default set to production, so first if you are a developer so change the environment to developer. Then save it and refresh your page. You must show the errors else blank page then if its your database mysql problem then you must firt try this it may help your problem.
go to config->database.php and open this file. Where you get

```
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
```

this line you must change this to -

```
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysqli';
```

Hope it will help if not then there must be any other problem.
Good luck

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. After looking at my database.php I notice that I was missing php_sqlsrv_71_ts_x64.dll in my php.ini.

Comment: Great, these small but very huge impact on the framework.

Answer (score 0):

You must check your php version... and I'm fixing this problem by

```
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysqli';
```