# How to correct the login page page which shows blank page on login in codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I have completed a project work on codeigniter which is done in localhost. I had uploaded the work on to a server and the website was working fine. After some days I moved into another server, when I checked the website the home page is working fine and there is no error in database connectivity but the login page in the website is not working. It is not showing a error page but a white blank page.

I had checked the version number. Its showing as CI 2.1 and PHP 5.6. Is it the problm of version ? Can anyone say a solution for this ? I checked a stackoverflow link like this [Codeigniter shows blank page with no error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29230694/codeigniter-shows-blank-page-with-no-error) But I didnt get a solution .Should I upgrade the version and how it is to be done ?

Comment: unable to help you unless you  show the code

Comment: which code do u wnt to see ?

Comment: You should upgrade if you're still using CI 2. But that's not related to your problem.

Comment: then whats the problem ?

Comment: don't know - need to find out what error is happening. either check your error logs or make the following modification to your index.php file and upload to server: https://pastebin.com/TuvLHDXn

Answer (score 0):

make sure your server has `mod_mysql` extension in php and `mod_rewrite` module ebnabled in the server

Comment: How to check that ?

Comment: is your website working fine and only login page not loading .??? or whole page ??