# php error doesn't get stored in apache logs

Tags: php, apache, error-logging

I am trying to inspect error in my php script. I went to the:

```
/var/log/httpd/error_log
```

but unfortunately, there is no errors originating in php, altohough I am clearly getting error 500 when running php script.

My php_ini on errors:

```
error_append_string     no value    no value
error_log               no value    no value
error_prepend_string    no value    no value
error_reporting         22527   22527
```

no value should mean that php logs get stored in the apache error logs. 
Any idea why this is happening an how to fix it? I am running centos 7

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6587515/how-to-display-php-errors-in-code-output

see this and add code to show error on view

Answer (score 1):

I am using https, so php logs errors in ssl_error_log.

Answer (score -1):

In /etc/php/5.6/apache2/php.ini file set `display_errors` from `Off` to `On`

Comment: Thanks, this displays error in browser, which is a working solution. What about logging it?

Comment: @sanjihan did u check in /var/log/apache2/error.log ?

Comment: I am on centos. I shoul add that info